# How to run qt qml application on startup

Tags: linux, qt, qml, autostart

I am using A20lime2 board with linux os. I have created qt qml desktop application .I am able to run application manually when system is fully booted.
 I want to run this gui application on startup without showing bootup msg and linux home page.
I have searched a lot for this, I tried different ways but didn't get it working.

1) I have tried simplest way that is  calling application in rc.local, this is working for python scripts but not for qt qml application

2) tried creating service in /etc/init.d and calling that script in rc.local but not getting anything. when I call my service manually using start and stop command I get error "job for xyz service failed. see 'systemctl status xyz service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details."
when I run 'systemctl status xyz service' , I get error "Active : failed...." 
and "Failed to start LSB: log file hand...." for journalctl -xn'

3) followed this procedure  https://debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian
getting no error but it is not running on startup.

Is there any other way ? or am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Can you post the `/etc/rc.local` script that you tried?

Comment: Are you looking for a "kiosk" mode of operation, where one graphical, full-screen application starts at boot, and nothing else can be executed? Or are you looking for an ordinary X desktop, that happens to have an application run automatically? Does the user need to authenticate, or not? I think the problem needs to be more clearly defined, but I suspect you'll get a better response on a Linux sysadmin forum.

Comment: Maybe you need [Boot to Qt](http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtee-about-b2qt.html)?

Comment: @KevinBoone I dont know much about kiosk mode of operation, is it for single application? I want to run 2-3 python scripts simultaneously in background. My requirement is application should run automatically on boot up and shut down when qt gui application is closed. Well Somehow I got my script working, now it runs on boot up but I need to put my root password for that. And when I close application it shows home screen which I dont want. How can I remove both password and homescreen?

Comment: @folibis  I am still learning qt so please tell me Do I need to install different kit for Boot to qt ? I have qt creator Desktop type kit  installed.

Comment: In general, you need to modify the X startup process so that, instead of launching a desktop, it launches your application(s) with appropriate user credentials. The launcher can just allow your application to run over and over, or exit when the application ends, in which case the system will shut down. This process is usually straightforward to implement for a specific Linux installation or distribution, and horrible guesswork without that information. That's why I think you'll get more focused guidance from a forum specific to your kind of Linux. It's not really a programming matter.

Comment: @KevinBoone Thank you so much, I'll try to get info from linux forum.